# In QGIS, how can 'Points along Geometry' give a significantly greater length than $length of a line?

Tags: qgis, length

If I use either QChainage or 'Points along Geometry' to put length markers along a route, I get a different (longer) total than if I calculate the whole line length with $length.

It's not trivial, nearly 0.5%, and it is longer while if anything, I would have expected it to have been shorter, with $length being based on ellipsoidal length.

Any idea how I can create a marker geometry that matches the $length?

[image]

Comment: Have you compared to `length($geometry)`?

Comment: Length($geometry) gives the same result as the endpoint distance marker on qchainage/points along geometry.

Comment: So the points distance along the line is based on planimetric measuring.